# Java new field getter null

Tags: java, syntax, nullpointerexception, hashmap, attributes

I am storing personalized items bound to a person in a map:

```
public class Steven {
    private HashMap<String, Object> myItems = new HashMap<>();

    public Object getMyItem(String key){
        Object i = myItems.get(key);
        if (i == null){
            myItems.put(key, new Integer(0));
            return getMyItem(key);
        }
        return i;
    }
}
```

so with external usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Steven steve = new Steven();
    int age = steve.getMyItem("age");
    System.out.printLn("steven's age is " + age + ", ");

    int[] eyeColors = steve.getMyItem("eye_colors");
    System.out.printLn("and his left eye's color idx is " + eyeColors[0] + ", and right eye's color idx is " + eyeColors[1]);
}
```

Obviously eyeColors would result in syntax failure. So is there any extra checks I could add to the getMyItem method so that it would return int[] if the stored item is null when I want an int[].

If so please any way that would not result in me needing to add an extra input to the method. i.e I don't want something like this:

```
public Object getMyItem(String key, Object ifNullThenThisNewInstance)
```

EDIT: Is there any universal Object that I can return so that:

```
int[] o = steve.getMyItem("thing1");
```

and

```
int o1 = steve.getMyItem("thing2");
```

would both work?

Comment: Your code would similarly not work if you just remove the issue of returning a not-null null value (since you can't assign an `Object` to an `int[]` or `int` as you tried to do it). You might want to address that first, or ask about that, before asking about the null problem.

Comment: What is the source for the value of age and eye colors?

Comment: What's the problem with returning `null`? The fact that you can't assign it to `int`? Do you want this to only work for `int` (or rather `Integer`) and `int[]`, or other classes as well? What should the default be for each class (this points to a problem with what you're trying to do)? This might be an interesting question, but it requires quite a bit of clarification first.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution would be to modify your method signature, so that atleast it can understand what kind of output you desire.
For example

```
int age = steve.getMyItem("age",1,"int"); // Being obvious that age for a person would be one number, second field here represents the data type your want your answer in

    int[] eyeColors = steve.getMyItem("eye_colors", 2,"int");//Again being obvious that a person has two eyes
//For example if you need String also
String hairColor = steve.getMytem("hair_color",1,"String");
```

The following can be the code for your Steven class

```
public class Steven {
            private HashMap<String, Object> myItems = new HashMap<>();

            public Object getMyItem(String key, int size, String datatype){
                Object i = myItems.get(key);
                if (i == null){
                    switch(datatype){
                     case "int":
                           int[] output = new int[size];
                           for(int j=0; j<size;j++){
                               output[j] = someSource.get(j); // Assuming you have some array with these numbers stored
                           }
                           myItems.put(key, output);
                          return size ==1 ? ((int[])output)[0]: output ;

                     case "String":
                     default:
                           String[] out = new String[size];
                           for(int j=0; j<size;j++){
                               out[j] = someSource.get(j); // Assuming you have some array with these numbers stored
                           }
                           myItems.put(key, out);
                          return size ==1 ? ((String[])out)[0]: out ;
                    }
                }
             return i;   
            }

    }
```

Comment: But I'm also using it to store string arrays etc.

Comment: It depends on you map's values source completely. You further add switch case or if/else conditions for different output datatypes, but in that case your method definition should take one more input parameter as what output you are expecting